# Why does the Fossil SCM use TEXT to store hashes?

Tags: database-design, hash, fossil

I was wondering how should I store a hash 
In the [Fossil SCM](http://fossil-scm.org), SHA1 hashes are stored as text of length 40.

```
CREATE TABLE blob(
  rid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  rcvid INTEGER,
  size INTEGER,
  uuid TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  content BLOB,
  CHECK( length(uuid)==40 AND rid>0 )
);
sqlite> select * from blob;
1|1|169|6fc9d28454d4d070ca863bbbdbf9835f3505d585|
2|2|687|f59c73c1dbdea48cd2330d5a309445d756fc6901|
3|2|221|84ddeef14a657366246e6d9dcb11e2b3669cd896|
4|3|695|0311113ca8c18fb3e83c9e35e0e49e373c089f08|
5|3|224|5c577d268419caea733544ba5c81932beead3bf7|
```

To a layman like myself it seems inefficient each character needs 8 bits, and gives 4 (0-f). I also I found that the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) to agree with me

> The size penalty for storing the hex
>   string in a CHAR column is at least
>   two times, up to eight times if the
>   value is stored in a column that uses
>   the utf8 character set (where each
>   character uses 4 bytes). Storing the
>   string also results in slower
>   comparisons because of the larger
>   values and the need to take character
>   set collation rules into account.

Is it that this column is not used as a key, and thus its size isn't such a big deal? No sir! From [`src/content.c@content_put:475`](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/artifact?name=37624e9e03d24cfb8274299090de0d90a378b50b) we can see

```
db_prepare(&s1, "SELECT rid, size FROM blob WHERE uuid=%B", &hash);
```

The fossil developer is smarter than me, so the hash is probably somehow stored in a compact binary form, however I don't understand how exactly is that happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is right, it's inefficient. However it helps debugging the software, and it takes relatively small amount of space, so it's a compromise between developer convenience and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Fossil does not rely on a MySQL database at all, but on an SQLite database. An SQLite database has [weak typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: of course it relies on SQLite (how do you think I got the schema? with `mysql fossilprj` ;-), however I still don't get, assuming the `SHA1` is stored in a binary form, how does the database convert the binary to a hex digest and vice versa. The fact that SQLite has weak types doesn't help me with understanding how it works efficiently.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich: Oh, I see what you mean. Yes, SHA1 sums are stored in plain text (you can lookup with a binary text editor for a sha1sum in the repository file, you will find it). I think there is no visible performance penalty. Moreover, ASCII characters take only 1 byte in UTF-8, so storage waste ratio is only 1:2.

Comment: and I take it that the indexer is smart enough to deduce a good index from the restriction on the column. Sounds a reasonable compromise, easier debugger for a bit more space.